# "detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed." on DELETE Method even if it's not set to GET (DRF + AJAX)

Tags: django, ajax, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to make a marketplace web project, Whenever I try to delete a Cart Product from cart, it redirects to an API view that shows that the GET method is not allowed. The delete function does not have a separate page, therefore it links to the api itself when the button is clicked.

I have double checked the urls of the api and they all are labelled correctly in the api side and in the ajax side when calling its function, yet it still shows said error.

Cart Viewset:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status, viewsets
from cart.models import Cart
from cart.serializers import CartSerializer, CartUpdateSerializer
from rest_framework.parsers import MultiPartParser, FormParser
class CartViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)

    # Function for adding products to user cart
    def addto_cart(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

        cartProduct = Cart.objects.filter(buyer = request.user.id)
        filtered = cartProduct.filter(product = self.kwargs.get("product_id")).first()
        print(filtered.cart_quantity)

        # Check if added cart product is a duplicate
        if cartProduct.filter(product = self.kwargs.get("product_id")).exists():
            print("Cart Product is a Duplicate!")
            serializerUpdate = CartUpdateSerializer(filtered, data=request.data, partial=True)
            #Only updates cart quantity
            if serializerUpdate.is_valid():
                addedQty = serializerUpdate.validated_data['cart_quantity']
                total = filtered.cart_quantity + addedQty
                serializerUpdate.save(cart_quantity = total)
                return Response(serializerUpdate.data, status = status.HTTP_200_OK)

        else:
            serializer = CartSerializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save(buyer=request.user)
                return Response(serializer.data, status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


    #Gets cart products
    def get_cart_products(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        cartProduct = Cart.objects.all()      
        if cartProduct:
            cartSerializer = CartSerializer(cartProduct, many=True)
            return Response(cartSerializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response(cartSerializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        
    #Deletes selected cart product if it exists
    def delete_cart_product(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        print('delete cart product accessed')
        cart_instance = Cart.objects.filter(buyer_id = request.user.id)
        cartProduct_instance = cart_instance.filter(product = self.kwargs.get("product_id")).first()

        if cart_instance.buyer_id != request.user.id:
            return Response(
                {"res": "You are not the owner of the cart!"},
                status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
            )
        cartProduct_instance.delete()
        return Response(
            {"res": "Cart Product Deleted!"},
            status = status.HTTP_200_OK
        )
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    #API urls
    path('api/addto_cart/<int:product_id>/', apis.CartViewSet.as_view({'post':'addto_cart'})),
    path('api/get_cart_products/<int:user_id>/', apis.CartViewSet.as_view({'get':'get_cart_products'})),
    path('api/delete_cart_product/<int:product_id>/', apis.CartViewSet.as_view({'delete':'delete_cart_product'})),

    #Views urls
    path('cart/<int:user_id>/', views.CartView.as_view(), name="cart"),

]
```

Serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Product, Cart

class CartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Cart
        fields = '__all__'

class CartUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Cart
        fields = ['cart_quantity']


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'

class ProductSellerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    seller = serializers.CharField(source = 'seller.get_full_name')
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
```

cart.js (AJAX)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var base_url = window.location.origin
    console.log('get cart test')
    console.log(base_url)
    var urlid = window.location.pathname
    var id = urlid.split("/")[3]
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: base_url + '/cart/api/get_cart_products/'+id+ '/',
        beforeSend: function() {
            console.log('before cart send');
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('cart get successful');
            console.log(data)

            $.each(data, function(index, cart) {
                console.log(cart.buyer)
                console.log(cart.product)
                if(cart.buyer == id) {
                    $.ajax({
                        method: 'GET',
                        url : base_url + '/market/api/get_productDetails/'+cart.product+ '/', 
                        beforeSend: function() {
                            console.log('before send');
                        },
                        success: function(product) {
                            displayCart(product.data,cart);
                            console.log(product.data.name);
                
                        },
                        error: function(error) {
                            console.log('sum ting wong get product detail', error);
                        }
                    });
                }
            })

        },
        error: function() {
            console.log('sum ting wong get cart');
        }
    });
});

// Delete Cart Product
$("#deleteCartProduct").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('Delete Cart Product test')
    var base_url = window.location.origin
    var urlid = window.location.pathname
    var id = urlid.split("/")[3]
    $.ajax({
        method: 'DELETE',
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        },
        url : base_url + '/cart/api/delete_cart_product/'+id+ '/', 

        success: function(response) {
            window.location = base_url + '/users/home/'
            console.log('cart product deleted!')
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log('sum ting wong delete cart product');
        }
    });
});

//append cart products to html
function displayCart(data,cart) {
    console.log(data)
    productID = data.id
    var base_url = window.location.origin
    let template = "";

        template += 

        "<div class='card mb-3' style='max-width: 540px;'>" +
        "<div class='row no-gutters'>" +
            "<div class='col-md-4'>" +
                "<img src= "+ data.picture +" class='card-img'>" +
            "</div>" +
            "<div class='col-md-8'>" +
                "<div class='card-body'>" +
                    "<h5 class='card-title'>"+ data.name +"</h5>" +
                    "<p class='card-text'><small class='text-muted'>"+ data.seller +"</small></p>" +
                    "<p class='card-text'>"+ data.description +"</p>" +
                    "<p class='card-text'>₱"+ data.price +"</p>" +
                    "<p class='card-text'>Quantity: "+ cart.cart_quantity +"</p>" +
                    "<p class='card-text'>Total Price: ₱"+ data.price * cart.cart_quantity +"</p>" +
                    "<a class='btn btn-primary' href="+base_url+"/market/productDetails/"+data.id+" role='button'>View</a>" +
                    //CONTAINS THE DELETE BUTTON
                    "<a class='btn btn-danger' id='deleteCartProduct' href="+base_url+"/cart/api/delete_cart_product/"+data.id+" role='button'>Delete</a>" +
                "</div>" +
            "</div>" +
        "</div>" +
    "</div>"       
        

    $('#cartProductDisplay').append(template)
}
```

I have also tried renaming the api, its url links and it still produces the same error. The api itself works when I test it on Postman.

Answer (score 0):

You made a simple mistake. Replace `type: 'DELETE'` to `method: 'DELETE'` in your `#deleteCartProduct` function

Comment: Hello, I've tried that and it's still produces the same error

i'll also edit it in the my post

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the proper way to change the request method in JQuery Ajax is to pass "DELETE" to the `type` parameter. It should work. If it is not check the request headers in your network tab on your browser and see if the request method is DELETE or not. This is how you can find out if it is a problem with your client-side or server-side app. If the problem persists on the client side consider using "Axios". It is more efficient and modern than JQuery Ajax.

Comment: I checked the request headers and it still uses the GET method.

What's weird is that i used similar code for deleting a product in the same project and it works normally. It would be a pain to switch to axios as im almost done with the project